# Preencher automaticamente os inputs com js / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Eu estava fazendo alguns testes com automação *JavaScript*/*jQuery* e me deparei com alguns sites que não é possível preencher as entradas corretamente.

Isto normalmente funcionaria na maioria dos sites:

```
$("#usuário").val('MY_USER')
$("#pass").val('MY_PASSWORD')
$("#send").click()
```

Mas, em alguns sites específicos, não funciona. Existe alguma maneira de criar um código que funcione em qualquer *input*?

Parece-me que um dos sites que estou testando verifica o evento de *keydown* para inserir o valor ao *input*.

Comment: Esta pergunta esta fora do escopo do Stack Overflow em Português, escreva somente perguntas em português do Brasil aqui, ou use o [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) para publicar esta pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe! editei para português!

Comment: Ha um acento no nome de um dos inputs `$("#usuário").val('MY_USER')` esse pode ser uma causa. Já vi sites possuírem incorretamente elementos com o mesmo `ID`, se um dos sites que você esta testando tiver essa condição esse também pode ser um problema. Use `console.log($("#usuário"))` para saber se o elemento retornado por essa consulta corresponde de fato ao _input_ desejado, e se possível compartilhe um dos sites que seu código não funciona assim como o código usado para termos um caso de teste.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `attr()`, que define um atributo:

```
$("#usuário").attr('value', 'MY_USER'); // Irá definir o atributo "value" para 'MY_USER'
$("#pass").attr('value', 'MY_PASSWORD'); // Irá definir o atributo "value" para 'MY_PASSWORD'
```

> OBS: A função `attr` pode definir qualquer atributo que você quiser.